# How to identify YML parse error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm getting the following error when I boot my rails 3.1.3 application:

```
psych.rb:148:in `parse': couldn't parse YAML at line 28 column 9 (Psych::SyntaxError)
```

I'm guessing it is related to YML file syntax.

The problem appears when I try running:

```
YAML.load_file "..."
```

From another rails 3.1.3 application and YMLs are loaded just fine.

Comment: Please avoid generally referring to other questions -- it doesn't improve the value of this question for other readers.

Comment: Found a solution. If you can't find a YML syntax error in your application locale files the problem might be in some of the locale files of a gem you might be using.

I introduced a breakpoint at base.rb:15 (of rails 3.1.3) and there you can see a list of all locale yml files that will be loaded under variable filenames.

Inspecting each one I finally found a file with an outdated YML file.

Comment: i'll post it as an answer in 8 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. If you can't find a YML syntax error in your application locale files the problem might be in some of the locale files of a gem you might be using.

I introduced a breakpoint at base.rb:15 (of rails 3.1.3) and there you can see a list of all locale yml files that will be loaded under variable filenames.

Inspecting each one I finally found a file with a

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is covered here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Syntax

An online parser, which may help you troubleshoot, is here: http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/